# Add and get sports and interest for a test user in facebook using javascript

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created a test app and test users for this test app in facebook.
I need to get sports and interest of this test user, to achieve this the test user must have sports and interests added to its facebook account. 
I login with the credentials for this test user but I am not able to add sports and interest for this user, when I try searching for any sports it gives me no results.
Refer below screenshot[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

All sports, music, interests, etc. the user can link to via their profile, are actually Facebook pages.

But test users can not interact with real pages. Can’t even see them, so you can not find them via the autocomplete functionality either.

Test users can theoretically create their own pages, but getting those to be visible to other test users, finding the right categories etc. might be difficult. It would really be easier if you added some real user accounts (friends) to the app in the Tester role (that is something different than a test user.)